# Program shows weird behavior after converting into .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, executable

I've made this simple program that runs in a console, the program runs fine in Visual Studio and once I try building it into an executable it shows weird behaviour.
The program opens, if I input 1, 3, 4 (or anything else) the program instantly ends and closes. If I input 2 the program accepts my input goes into 'second stage' and then anything that I input ends the programs instantly. What's causing this issue and how can I successfully turn my code into an executable.

Note: this program uses a .txt file in case 3, tried including it inside the build and still did not change anything. Also I do know that switch case could have been better than chained if statements here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct Staff {
    string emri;
    string mbiemri;
    int paga;
    string poz;
    void printStaff() const {
        cout << "Emri: " << emri << '\n';
        cout << "Mbiemri: " << mbiemri << '\n';
        cout << "Paga Mujore: " << paga << '\n';
        cout << "Pozicioni i punes: " << poz << '\n';
    }
};
 
struct Pizza {
    string lloji;
    int cmimi;
    string ingredientet;
    void printPizza() const {
        cout << "Emri i pizzes: " << lloji << '\n';
        cout << "Cmimi: " << cmimi << '\n';
        cout << "Ingredientet: " << ingredientet << '\n';
    }
};
 
void staffInfo() {
    cout << "Zgjidhni nje nga pjesetaret e staffit:" << "\n";
    cout << " " << "\n";
    cout << "1. Ben Dover" << "\n";
    cout << "2. Hugh Jass" << "\n";
    cout << "3. Mohammed Abdul" << "\n";
    cout << "4. Danilo Lopez" << "\n";
    cout << "5. Itachi Uchiha" << "\n";
    cout << "6. Elon Musk" << "\n";
    cout << " " << "\n";
    cout << "Vendos numrin e pjesetarit: ";
 
}
 
void pizzaInfo() {
    cout << "Zgjidhni nje nga pizzat:" << "\n";
    cout << " " << "\n";
    cout << "1. Macho" << "\n";
    cout << "2. La Patata Loca" << "\n";
    cout << "3. Rukola Crudo Parmigiano" << "\n";
    cout << "4. Love Love" << "\n";
    cout << "5. Polka" << "\n";
    cout << "6. Pepperoni" << "\n";
    cout << "7. Tuna Double Cheese" << "\n";
    cout << " " << "\n";
    cout << "Vendos numrin e pizzes: ";
 
}
 
void printMag() {
    ifstream Mag("magazina.txt");
    string line;
    while (Mag.good()) {
        getline(Mag, line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
 
void info() {
    cout << "When the pizza is too good, it`s Proper Pizza" << "\n";
    cout << "Numri i telefonit: +355697778888" << "\n";
    cout << "Website: www.properpizza.al" << "\n";
    cout << "Vendndodhja: Rruga e Kavajes, Godina 12, Tirane, Albania" << "\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        system("Color 7C");
 
        cout << "   Miresevini ne sistem!" << "\n";
        cout << "Zgjidhni nje nga kategorite:" << "\n";
        cout << " " << "\n";
        cout << "1. Informacione rreth restorantit" << "\n";
        cout << "2. Staffi" << "\n";
        cout << "3. Menuja " << "\n";
        cout << "4. Magazina " << "\n";
        cout << " " << "\n";
        cout << "5. Exit the program " << "\n";
        cout << " " << "\n";
        cout << "Vendos numrin e kategorise: ";
 
        Staff s1{ "Ben", "Dover", 50000, "Kamarier" };
        Staff s2{ "Hugh", "Jass", 35000, "Ndihmes Kamarier" };
        Staff s3{ "Mohammed", "Abdul", 50000, "Ndihmes Kuzhinier" };
        Staff s4{ "Danilo", "Lopez", 65000, "Shef Kuzhinier" };
        Staff s5{ "Itachi", "Uchiha", 35000, "Pastrues" };
        Staff s6{ "Elon", "Musk", 250000, "CEO" };
 
        Pizza p1{ "Macho", 1250, "Marinated Sauce, Susam, Proper Cheese, Macho Sauce, Herba Cipolina, Proper Ham, Small Risole" };
        Pizza p2{ "La Patata Loca", 1350, "Proper Cheese, Loca Sauce, Mozzarella Fior Di Latte, Potatoes, Calf Rissole, Sauce 4 Cheeses, Susam" };
        Pizza p3{ "Rukola Krudo Parmigiano", 1550, "Marinated Sauce, Susam, Proper Cheese, Parmigiano, Rucola, Olive Oil" };
        Pizza p4{ "Love Love", 1000, "Marinated Sauce, Susam, Proper Cheese, Peppers, Napoletan Ham, Gorgonzola" };
        Pizza p5{ "Polka", 1200, "Sauce 4 Cheeses, Susam, Proper Cheese, Mozzarella Fior Di Latte, Pecorine, Alfredo Sauce, Sausage" };
        Pizza p6{ "Pepperoni", 1050, "Marinated Sauce, Susam, Proper Cheese, Sausage" };
        Pizza p7{ "Tuna Double Cheese", 1250, "Marinated Sauce, Susam, Tuna, Double Cheese" };
 
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        cout << " " << "\n";
        if (input == 1) {
            info();
        }
        else if (input == 2) {
            cout << " " << "\n";
            staffInfo();
            int staffinput;
            cin >> staffinput;
            cout << " " << "\n";
            if (staffinput == 1) {
                s1.printStaff();
            }
            else if (staffinput == 2) {
                s2.printStaff();
            }
            else if (staffinput == 3) {
                s3.printStaff();
            }
            else if (staffinput == 4) {
                s4.printStaff();
            }
            else if (staffinput == 5) {
                s5.printStaff();
            }
            else if (staffinput == 6) {
                s6.printStaff();
            }
            else {
                cout << " " << "\n";
                cout << "Ju lutem vini emrin e nje prej pjesetareve!" << "\n";
            }
 
        }
        else if (input == 3) {
            pizzaInfo();
            int pizzainput;
            cin >> pizzainput;
            cout << " " << "\n";
            if (pizzainput == 1) {
                p1.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 2) {
                p2.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 3) {
                p3.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 4) {
                p4.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 5) {
                p5.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 6) {
                p6.printPizza();
            }
            else if (pizzainput == 7) {
                p7.printPizza();
            }
            else {
                cout << " " << "\n";
                cout << "Ju lutem vini emrin e nje prej pizzave" << "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (input == 4) {
            printMag();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Mirupafshim!" << "\n";
 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you run it in the IDE it is also an executable. It appears you have a `break` at the end of the `while` loop. This would cause the program to exit because it is finished.

Comment: The program did not have that break at the end. After posting it on another forum and asking multiple people a lot of them suggested that wrapping the whole program inside a while loop should fix the issue (which it didn't). And the program runs exactly the same with and without a while loop

Comment: Ok, without the `while` loop if you press 1 the program will print 4 lines of text then exit. If you're running it by double clicking it in Explorer it's likely you will not be able to see the text before it exits. Try running it from a command line.

Comment: Off-Topic: When you need more than 3 of the same instance, consider using `std::vector`.  A vector will also all you to iterate through values easier than accessing as separate variables.

Comment: IMHO, using a `switch` statement is much cleaner and easier to read and maintain than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you get to the end of your program, it ends. If you run the executable, the Windows window will simply close at the end. To avoid this, open a command prompt at the executable level, then run the program from that command prompt.

[image]

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue (kind of). Running it through cmd did give some sort of a desired output but the problem relied with my logic. I messed with the loop for some time and came up with an alternative solution. My program now runs in an infinite loop until the user doesn't go into a desired category (If the user presses 5 on the first stage or any other button).